# How can I mutate a dataframe to turn biological replicates into columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have qPCR data with 3 replicates per sample.

Right now, I have a dataframe with 4 columns, "Content", "Sample", "Replicate", and "Cq":

```
  Content Sample Replicate    Cq
1     Std  Std 6         1 26.86
2     Std  Std 5         1 23.64
3     Std  Std 4         1 20.41
4     Std  Std 3         1 16.72
5     Std  Std 2         1 12.80
6     Std  Std 1         1  9.46
```

I want to turn the "Replicate" column into 3 columns == "Rep 1", "Rep 2", and "Rep 3". Then, I want the columns filled with the Cq data that belongs to each sample.

```
  Content Sample  Rep 1   Rep 2   Rep 3
1     Std  Std 6  26.86   26.83   26.71
2     Std  Std 5  23.64   23.79   23.60
3     Std  Std 4  20.41   20.44   20.34
4     Std  Std 3  16.72   17.22   16.85 
5     Std  Std 2  12.80   12.35   12.55
6     Std  Std 1  9.46    9.56    9.40
```

Is there a way to do this?

I tried to use mutate() from dplyr. I combined the columns of "Replicate" and "Cq", but was unsure how to move on from there. I'm not even sure this is the right approach -- it's been a while since I've used R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_wider(df1, names_from = Replicate, values_from = Cq, names_prefix = "Rep")
```